# What does code #emailheader do exactly? Does it fall under HTML or CSS?

Tags: html

I have a code in my email template. This is just basic, but I'm starting off and no amount of Googling is helpful. I understand what it does to a certain extent, but I could not find this syntax in HTML or CSS, so I'm curious what does it do exactly, and can we do away with it.

```
#emailHeader {
        table-layout: fixed;
        font-family:  Arial;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 22px;
    }

    #emailHeader td {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
```

Comment: This is CSS, and it sets the display style for matching HTML elements.  Aside from that it's not really clear what you're asking...

Comment: This standard CSS syntax for formatting said element, `mailHeader`, using the id selector `#`. `#emailheader td` selects `td` elements within said original element with said id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help your understanding:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Basically, the code you posted in CSS styling for the element with the ID `emailHeader` and styling for any `td` element within it.

Whether or not you can remove depends on if you need that styling or not.

Comment: Wow great. Basically it is an id selector. Syntax '#" was the main question. I know about class selectors and syntax but did not know about ID selector. Now I know. 
Thank you very much